# github pages doesn't include all subdirectories

Tags: github, github-pages

## Description

Trying out github pages with a project that files are organized like this:

```
/index.html
/landingpage/css/styles.css
/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css
```

in `index.html` including the project's specific css file works:

```
 <link href="landingpage/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

but including vendor's css file doesn't:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
```

When loading the page, I get a 200 http response to:

```
GET https://loicjaouen.github.io/landingpage/landingpage/css/styles.css
```

and a 404 to:

```
GET https://loicjaouen.github.io/landingpage/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css
```

## Question

What's wrong with including a `vendor` subdir that prevents github pages from serving files inside `vendor`?

## Reference

https://github.com/loicjaouen/landingpage/tree/original-brokenlinks

Answer (score 1):

## first attempt

Move subdir `vendor` inside existing `landingpage`.

See code at https://github.com/loicjaouen/landingpage/tree/brokenlinks

That worked... but it was not quite satisfactory to guess that only one subdir could be included.

## second attempt

Leave subdir `vendor` at root level and rename it to `other`.

See code at: https://github.com/loicjaouen/landingpage/tree/non-vendor-subdir

That worked too: apparently including a subdir named `vendor` is not allowed